# What is wrong with the function below?

Tags: r, function

Should go through values of a vector of length 17 and return starts based on the values in the vector.

```
star <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:17){
        if(x>1){
            print("")
       }if(1>x>0.1) {
            print(".")
       }if(0.1>x>0.05) {
            print("*")
       }if(0.05>x>0.01) {
           print("**")
       }if(0.01>x) {
           print("***")
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why do we need x? Why do we never use i? What is the end goal? Just use `findInterval`/`cut`/`between`.

Comment: Even `ifelse` will do here

Comment: why not use stars.pval() from gtools? This does almost exactly what you are trying to do: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/stars.pval

Comment: What is this, 1995? Stars for p values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write the function like this:

```
star <- function(x) {
  for(v in x){
    if(v <= 0.01){
      print('***')
    }else if(v <= 0.05){
      print('**')
    } else if(v <= 0.1){
      print('*')
    } else if(v <= 1){
      print('.')
    }else{
      print('')
    }
  }
}
```

try it on

```
values <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5:17)
```

it will return

```
> star(values)
[1] "***"
[1] "**"
[1] "*"
[1] "."
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
```